# How to use ADP with Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

In my application I create ADP and then import it into my `.accdb` file. But when I use my application on Access 2013 then I do not import my ADP data into my `.accdb` file because Office 2013 does not support ADP. Now I want the solution of this problem with no change in my previous work so that my application will work on all Office versions. How can I use my ADP in my `.accdb` on Access 2013?

Comment: When you ask "how do I use my ADP in Access 2013", are you asking how you continue to develop your application in 2013, or asking how someone who only has 2013 can use your application?  If it's the latter, you might get away with deploying the Access 2010 runtime onto the computers of your end users.  The runtime has no design capabilities, but if you are simply deploying your application, you might be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Umm, I believe the essence of the answer to your question is ***in*** your question...

> Office 2013 does not support ADP

...so the answer to...

> How can I use my ADP in my .accdb on Access 2013?

...is:

You don't.

You can use ADP, or you can use Access 2013: Pick one.